# How to extract single values from vector_float2

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

ARKit's `ARFaceGeometry` class has a property
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) const vector_float2 *textureCoordinates NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;`

How can I get U-V coordinates from the single textureCoord entry? For `vector_float3` type, I'm using `SCNVector3FromFloat3` method to get the `SCNVector3` type from which I can get x,y,z values.

But how about vector_float2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `(*textureCoordinates)[0]` and `(*textureCoordinates)[1]`, when it is not `nil`?

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what works out of the box, but it led me to the right solution: `vector_float2 f2 = anchor.geometry.textureCoordinates[i]; float u = f2[0]; float v = f2[1];` seems to do the job.